# Writeline doesn't write to 3rd and 4th lines

Tags: python, tkinter, file-handling

Weirdly, even tho these are same codes, line 3 and line 4 write on line 5 in txt file.

Here is the code:

```
def save():
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines([filename1, "\n"+filename2, "\n"+filename3, "\n"+filename4, "\n"+filename5+"\n"])
```

When all filnames are "a"

Output is:

```
a
a


a
```

When only filename3 is "a"

Output is:

```
a
```

And I take the filename with this code

```
filename3 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
```

Here is the relevant code

```py
filename1 = ""
filename2 = ""
filename3 = ""
filename4 = ""
filename5 = ""

def uploadFile3(fname):
    global filename3
    filename3 = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    fname.config(text=filename3)

def save():
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines([filename1, "\n"+filename2, "\n"+filename3, "\n"+filename4, "\n"+filename5+"\n"])

buttonc = tk.Button(window, text="Add File", command= lambda: uploadFile3(program3)).pack()
program3 = Label(window, text=filename3)
program3.pack()

buttonaa = Button(window, text="Save", command=save)
```

These are hard-coded right now, there are 5 functions named uploadFile1, uploadFile2 and so on.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: can you paste all the relevant code

Comment: Sure, I edited the post

Comment: It is still avoiding 3 and 4

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem is with the way you are embedding the `\n` in the output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you feel the need to number variables, don't.  Use a list, e.g.:

```
filename = ["","","","",""]
```

Access as `filename[0]` - `filename[4]`.

then join all your strings with a newline.  Using `print` redirected to a file will provide the final newline for the last line as well:

```
filename=['a','b','c','','d']
with open('save.txt','w') as f:
    print('\n'.join(filename),file=f)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
filename1 = "a"
filename2 = "b"
filename3 = "c"
filename4 = "d"
filename5 = "e"



def save():
    with open("save.txt", "w") as f:
        f.writelines([filename1, "\n"+filename2, "\n"+filename3, "\n"+filename4, "\n"+filename5+"\n"])
```

I get the following output.

```
a
b
c
d
e
```

Your save function works fine

Comment: It actually worked, so the problem is upload function...

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative based on your code snippets:

```py
def save(lines):
    with open('save.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines('\n'.join(lines))
```

And then you can simply call `save()` as:

```py
save([filename1, filename2, filename3, filename4, filename5])
```